# How can I add my own CPS Project type in a C# or C++ project type as reference?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I need to use a CPS project system that generates a dll file as a reference in both a c# project and a c++ project, but when I add the project as reference in those projects, the IDE throws me an exception:

A reference to myCpsProject could not be added

I think it's because my CPS project system needs another capability, but I don't know how to implement it. How can I fix this error?
[This is the process what I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O79K.jpg)

Comment: They are incompatible project types, the .JS web project can't be referenced because that project is not compiled to a format that is callable by the referencing project. What is a "CPS" project?

Comment: It is a simple example. The real project type that I want to add as reference, generates dll files when it compiles.

Comment: What is the actual project type though? A "dll" isn't necessarily usable by the .NET reference system, you would need to do `DllImport` for unmanged code for example, and not use the reference.

Comment: Then, CPS is an extension of visual studio that allows you to add a new kind of project with other programming language that is not included in VS 2017

Comment: I'm guessing this generates an unmanaged DLL instead of a managed one, you'll need to use `DllImport` statements and a wrapper in .NET (C#/VB.NET) to call into it/reference it. You can only add references through the "References" folder to managed .NET or COM projects.

Comment: The actual project type is a new kind of project that supports a new programming language that is not supported in visual studio without an extension. It generates a "dll" file that need to be referenced in a c++ and c# project types, that's it.

Comment: I understand, but what I'm saying is that unless your generated dll file is a registered COM DLL, or a .NET assembly, you can't add it via the "References" folder. The *only* way to reference that type of unmanaged project is to use `DllImport` and wrapper functions inside a .NET assembly.

Comment: Ok, but the generated dll is a .NET assembly because my programming language generates c# files and then compiles them into a dll file. I think the problem is in the xml project structure,